# Delay href execution with jquery

Tags: jquery, href, transition, delay, location-href

I am trying to create a small page transition with jQuery

I have this list of links

```
<div class="work">
    <div class="item" data-fx="5">
        <a href="project-page.html" data-img="assets/testimage.png"><span>Ude bag November Vej</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-fx="5">
        <a href="project-page.html" data-img="assets/testimage.png"><span>Rabbit</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-fx="5">
        <a href="" data-img="assets/testimage.png"><span>Camouflage no. 1</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-transition-out"></div>
```

When ever a link is clicked, i would like to delay the link for a small animation to run, before it sends you to the page.

I use this jquery code to achieve it

```
$(".work .item").click(function() {
    $(".page-transition-out").css("height","100vh");

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    setTimeout(function() {window.location = href}, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

It kinda works.
It delays the link and runs the animation.

But i get an *undefined* url

Can anyone help+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.work .item` element - that is, the `this` inside the handler, is the `<div>`, not the `<a>`. To navigate to the child `<a>`, do:

```
var href = this.children[0].href;
```

Or if you prefer the jQuery syntax

```
var href = $(this).children().attr('href');
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot.